# can fancybox show next/previous buttons if using "append content" only?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I'm trying to use fancybox to "append custom content (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)
I just want to open the popup with my own div, and I want the next/previous buttons to appear. I got fancy box working fine with the other examples, but when I use the custom content example, the next and previous buttons don't show. Is there a way to get them to show with the custom content method?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you have a `rel` attribute in your link(s), don't you?

Comment: no, like this:
<!— link  —>

<a href="#test" class="fancybox"><img src="img/car.jpg" style="max-height:75px;"></a>

<!— extra content div appears inside the fancy box popup—>

<div id="test" style="display:none;max-width:600px; text-align:center;">
 by extra content 
</div>

The box and content appears fine, but no < > icons to go to the next one

Comment: well, I guess you should add the same `rel` attribute as in the gallery you want them to appear